# Printing this variable in smarty

Tags: smarty

I'm having an array $customPre. I want to print the element of the array "Please specify which fund". I am doing like this:

```
{$customPre.Please specify which fund}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use PHP-like syntax that is similar to PHP: `{$variable['key']}`.

If In PHP you have:

```
$smarty->assign('customPre', array ('Please specify which fund' => 'This is value'));
```

In Smarty you need to use:

```
{$customPre['Please specify which fund']}
```

And the output for this will be:

> This is value

I believe you cannot use in this case dot syntax ( `{$customPre.Please specify which fund}`) because it's probably looks for whitespaces in keys. Even adding quotes won't help.

Comment: No. Its not working({$customPre['Please specify which fund']}). Still gives me blank value

Comment: @user3259992  So you should show how and what exactly you assign from PHP to Smarty